# Knockout.js is not working with webpack in rails 6

Tags: javascript, webpack, knockout.js, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to install Knockout.js in rails 6 using webpack. But ko is not working.

**Added knockout package using yarn**

yarn add knockout

Then imported knockout in application.js

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
import "bootstrap"
import "knockout"
import "../stylesheets/application"
```

Getting error 
*Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout depends on the global variable `ko` being present.

```
var ko = require("knockout");
```